# How to generate multiple graphs with for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, save-image

I would like to generate a series of graphs with for loops. For each graph I have a csv file and different titles. Each graph should be saved as PNG and SVG. Each graph is to be generated in different styles (=themes).

All the csv files have three columns (year, type, value) and the graph is a line graph with the years as X and the value for Y axis. Each "type" results in a line on the graph.

I started out creating a script for a single graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

filename = "firstgraph"
filename_csv = paste0(filename,".csv")
titlestring = "Title of [firstgraph]"
labelstrings = c("\"label1\"", "\"label2\"", "\"label3\"")

my.data <- read.csv(file=filename_csv, sep = ";", header = TRUE)

# Plot
my.data %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=year, y=value, group=type, color=type)) +
  geom_line(size=1.5) +
  labs(title = titlestring, 
       subtitle = "static subtitle", 
       x = "Jahr", 
       y = "%", 
       caption = "static caption") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1800,2015,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) +
  theme_economist() + scale_color_economist(labels = labelstrings, 
                                            name = "Variante") -> plot_1

plot_1

svg(filename=paste0("plot_",filename,".svg"), 
    width=16, 
    height=7, 
    pointsize=12)
plot_1
dev.off()

png(filename=paste0("plot_",filename,".png"), 
    type = "cairo",
    width=2000, 
    height=800, 
    pointsize=16,
    res=96)
plot_1
dev.off()
```

This works fine and generates a SVG and a PNG version of the said graph.
Now I'd like to do this for a series of graphs and extended the script with for loops.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

styles <- c("1", "2")
filenames <- c("firstgraph", "secondgraph")
labelstring_list <- matrix(list(), nrow=2, ncol=1)
labelstring_list[[1,1]] <- c("\"label1\"", "\"label2\"", "\"label3\"")
labelstring_list[[2,1]] <- c("\"label2_1\"", "\"label2_2\"", "\"label2_3\"")

i = as.integer(1)
for(mname in filenames) 
  {
  filename_csv = paste0(mname,".csv")
  titlestring = paste0("Entwicklung des Gebrauchs von [", mname, "]")
  labelstrings = labelstring_list[i]

  my.data <- read.csv(file=filename_csv, sep = ";", header = TRUE)

  my.data %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=year, y=value, group=type, color=type)) +
    geom_line(size=1.5) +
    labs(title = titlestring, 
         subtitle = "static subtitle", 
         x = "Jahr", 
         y = "%", 
         caption = "static subtitle") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1800,2015,10)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,100,10)) -> plot_1

  for(style in styles)
    {
    if(style=="1") 
      {
      plot_1 +
        theme_economist() + scale_color_economist(labels = labelstrings, 
                                                  name = "Variante") -> plot_x
      }
    if(style=="2") 
      {
      plot_1 +
        theme_wsj()+ scale_colour_wsj("colors6",labels = labelstrings, 
                                      name = "Variante") -> plot_x
      }

    svg(filename=paste0("plot_",mname,"_",style,".svg"), 
        width=16, 
        height=7, 
        pointsize=12)
      plot_x
    dev.off()

    png(filename=paste0("plot_",mname,"_",style,".png"), 
        type = "cairo",
        width=2000, 
        height=800, 
        pointsize=16,
        res=96)
      plot_x
    dev.off()

    }

  i = (i+1)
  }
```

This does not work anymore. I have no errors in the console and the following files are created:

- plot_firstgraph_1.svg
- plot_firstgraph_2.svg
- plot_secondgraph_1.svg
- plot_secondgraph_2.svg

These files are all 223 bytes and are empty. The expected PNG files are NOT created.

I checked with `print()` if the right names and such are in the variables and all seems fine:

```
  print(mname)
  print(filename_csv)
  print(titlestring)
  print(labelstrings)
```

This outputs:

```
[1] "firstgraph"
[1] "firstgraph.csv"
[1] "Entwicklung des Gebrauchs von [firstgraph]"
[[1]]
[1] "\"label1\""   "\"label2\"" "\"label3\"" 

[1] "secondgraph"
[1] "secondgraph.csv"
[1] "Entwicklung des Gebrauchs von [secondgraph]"
[[1]]
[1] "\"label2_1\""   "\"label2_2\"" "\"label2_3\""
```

This seems all fine to me but as I said, the PNGs are not created and the SVGs are empty. I tried generating only PNGs (and no SVGs) which did not work.

Could anyone tell me where I make a mistake?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: while it is nice that you shared your code, it would be ideal if could post a reproducible example using any generated data, or some other data (e.g. from package datasets).

Comment: Inside a `for` loop autoprint is not active, you must call `print(your_plot)` explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to replace

```r
png(filename=paste0("plot_",mname,"_",style,".png"), 
    type = "cairo",
    width=2000, 
    height=800, 
    pointsize=16,
    res=96)
  plot_x
dev.off()
```

by

```r
plot_x
mirror <- recordPlot()
png(filename=paste0("plot_",mname,"_",style,".png"), 
    type = "cairo",
    width=2000, 
    height=800, 
    pointsize=16,
    res=96)
replayPlot(mirror)
dev.off()
```

in your loop and re-test ?

Comment: I tried to do that and the PNGs get created. The SVGs stayed empty. I changed the script so it also does the record_plot() and now all images get generated. For the moment they all have the same data (despite having different data files) but this is another issue I'll check now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, of course you have to adapt the code as well for the svg generation part.